Dual GPUs and dual operating systems
I want to install Windows in my current precision system. I already have Ubuntu 20.04, 2 Nvidia RTX 5000 16GB, 64GB RAM, and a 20 core 4.3 GHz Xeon processor. Can I add my Windows OS as a dual boot alongside Ubuntu? I want to play games on it. I also run computer vision algorithms with the 2 GPUs right now.

Will installing Windows alongside Ubuntu change the driver version I'm running in Ubuntu?

I don't want the software for the physical hardware to change if I install Windows alongside Ubuntu. Getting the right driver version in my Ubuntu was hard and demanding, and I don't want to add Windows OS if it will change my currently installed GPU driver or my CUDA version.

The NVidia driver is installed as part of the OS.  If you choose to dual boot your computer by adding Windows, then you will also install NVidia drivers within Windows, which are separate from Ubuntu and the drdivers you have installed there.

My personal experience - as someone not very experienced - is that installing Windows after Ubuntu caused no end of problems, but the other way round was fine. When Windows installs, it can overwrite things that are essential for Ubuntu (including grub). I’m certain it’s possible, but it might be much easier to install Windows then reinstall Ubuntu. Whatever route you take, expect that you may end up with an unbootable Ubuntu and have to reinstall - so prepare the media and have robust backups.

I’m voting to close this question because it is about installing Windows, and so not about Ubuntu.

You might want to ask on our sister site [su] instead since we cannot help you with the Windows side of things here.

In a dual boot computer Windows and Ubuntu are two separate operating systems, and installing software in one OS will not have any effect on the software that is installed in the other OS except for installing, removing or modifying the bootloader.
Installing Windows will not change the driver version you're running in Ubuntu. Installing Windows will not change the version of any other software that you are running in Ubuntu either, but you may need to run Boot-Repair to repair the grub bootloader after you finish installing Windows as a dual boot alongside Ubuntu because Windows often disregards the bootloader of any non-Windows OS that is installed alongside it.
